# We have noticed that a tool window "Error List" is slowing Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Today my Visual Studio 2017 crashed during debug phase and after I restarted it, it showed this message:

"We've noticed that a tool window "Error List" is slowing Visual Studio"

What does it mean?

Comment: It just means it is very confused, probably because it crashed.  Ignore.

Comment: It seems that there is [no fix](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/21742/weve-noticed-muiltiple-tool-windows-are-slowing-vi.html) at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think they resolved with Visual Studio 2017 update 15.6.0 as described here

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/30884/error-list-slowing-visual-studio.html